# How can I store language resource files in a different directory than the default?

Tags: c#, internationalization

I have a C# application that is being internationalized. I want to keep all of my language resource directories (en-US, es-SP, etc...) in a single directory called "languages" within the installation directory, so that the file path would be something like C:\application\
languages\en-US\resource.dll for each compiled resource file.

Unfortunately, the .dll that references the language resource file is in the C:\application\mainprogram.dll location. What do I need to set in Visual Studio so that mainprogram.dll can correctly access all of my language resource dll files?

Also of note is that the language resource files work fine if all of their folders are on the same level as the mainprogram.dll file.

Comment: Not a problem Shaun hard to tell when they don't truly specify .np thou

Answer (score 3):

You can specify additional private paths using the [Probing Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your configuration.

Alternatively and probably more than you would need:

You can hook in to the [AppDomains Assembly resolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) event which gets called every time it fails to find an assembly via standard probing.